# Spring MySQL : Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'

Tags: spring

I am creating a MySQL connection , but I have a problem with **applicationContextMySQL** and **web.xml**.

I have this content in **web.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <!-- Automáticamente inicializa el contexto spring con el formato servlet-name=nombre-servlet.xml -->
        <servlet-name>prueba</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <!--  
        La alternativa de inicialización de spring MVC es mediante un init-param como se describe 
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/prueba-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>-->
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>prueba</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContextMySQL.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener> 
<!-- Spring security filtro -->
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In the **applicationContextMySQL**.xml , I have this content.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/inicio.do" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="myDataSource" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/m12spring" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

The exactly error in the code.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContextMySQL.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:725)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:189)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1910)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3063)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1830)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:875)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:82)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:753)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:263)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:67)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:601)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:343)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:895)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1422)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:454)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:643)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Comment: PLease specify erroe

Comment: The error was in the title : Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'

Comment: specify entire  error in question itself.

Comment: @jcsa he means full stacktrace with the root cause.

Comment: I need to show all error?

Answer (score 0):

You can see in your log :  `Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]`

Are your sure that you have import the class with adding **commons-dbcp** dependency ?

If it's not the case, just add this in your **pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```